# CSS div using viewport size instead of parent size

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to learn CSS on a pretty experimental way (Still pretty n00b though) by creating the ubuntu logo on pure CSS. The HTML i am using right now is at http://pastebin.com/LuUABXFq and its been working properly with pixel dimensions, but ive wanted to swap those hardcoded values for percentage ones to allow me to render the logo at any resolution and still have it render out with good proportions.

In this process i've been puzzled by a question: Why does #ubuntu-CoF-faceBackground converts percentage to pixels using the viewport size instead of the #ubuntu-CoF-background parent instance's size? Right now, that code renders to a really big purple rectangle over a white square, whereas the purple rectangle should be half the size of the white square. (Tested on Firefox 15 and Chromium 20 on Fedora 17 x64)

Semi-functional code for this can be found at my github: https://github.com/Drknzz/HTML-Experiments/blob/master/UbuntuLogo.html, i just need to align the Circle of Friends roundel to the top of the text to comply with the ubuntu brand guidelines.